# Empty securerandom.strongAlgorithms Security Property

Tags: java, java-8, jce, java-security, secure-random

When I am setting up as a application in Jenkins. The code works fine in local and other build environments. In Jenkins i am getting this error during the build and unit tests. Our application only needed external change is download JCE (Jave Crypto Extension) from oracle and replace the policy jars in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security folder.  that I did. I can see log it is picking up those jars.  Still i see below error. Do i need to do anything for secure random?    `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();` is causing the issue. any help?

```
[ERROR] Null/empty securerandom.strongAlgorithms Security Property
[ERROR]     at com.test.cipher.AesGcmCipher.generate(AesGcmCipher.java:72)
[ERROR]     at com.test.scheme.Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest$1.getDefaultCipher(Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest.java:27)
[ERROR]     at com.test.scheme.Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest$1.getDefaultCipher(Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest.java:24)
[ERROR]     at com.test.CachingCryptoCipherProvider.<init>(CachingCryptoCipherProvider.java:43)
[ERROR]     at com.test.CryptoCipherProvider.asCachingProvider(CryptoCipherProvider.java:28)
[ERROR]     at com.test.scheme.Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest.createAesGcmProvider(Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest.java:35)
[ERROR]     at com.test.scheme.Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest.<init>(Version1CryptoSchemeAesGcmTest.java:20)
[ERROR]     ... 28 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Null/empty securerandom.strongAlgorithms Security Property
[ERROR]     at java.security.SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong(SecureRandom.java:627)
[ERROR]     at com.test.cipher.AesGcmCipher.generate(AesGcmCipher.java:62)
[ERROR]     ... 34 more`
```

Below is my java code.

```
public class AesGcmCipher {
    public static AesGcmCipher generate(BiConsumer<AesGcmCipher, SecretKey> consumer) {
        try {
            UUID cipherId = UUID.randomUUID();
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
            KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(AES);
            AesGcmCipher cipher = new AesGcmCipher(cipherId, secretKey, new Date());
            return cipher;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(msg);
            throw new CryptoException(msg, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

FYI Jenkins is running on `java version "1.8.0_73"`.  The code which is running perfectly on other machines with version `1.8.0_51` and `1.8.0_91`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an issue with your jdk. Could you verify this file `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`:

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/random
securerandom.strongAlgorithms=NativePRNGBlocking:SUN
```

This is my configuration, probably you'll need to reinstall JDK

Comment: I have it in my local but not there in jenkins java. i have added but still it is not working.

Comment: After upgrading to latest version of java `1.8.0_191-b12` it is working fine.